# Is watching videos to earn money Haram?

Tags: halal-haram

Salam! I just started to earn money by watch 10,20,30 minutes videos and after watching it they give me an amount of money. based on how many minutes the video was.But what I watch is educational,persuasive and etc.. So may I know if it is Haram???

Comment: Can I ask you how you earn money by watching videos?

Comment: please share the site, so I can know how it works.